# Mobile Application of a web page (Android Studio)

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

Is it possible to get data from a web site made with moodle and use it on android studio? I do not have access to API's .
I only have username and password for the site.

Example:

[link to example moodle site](http://moodle.ciu.edu.tr/?lang=en) <<<< is it possible to get data separately from that site after log-in

ps. i do not want to use "webview"

thanks in advance

Comment: That is called web scrapping

Comment: Yes, but it is relatively hard because any change on the target website's HTML  will break your application.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It might be the best way to ask for the API's . Have a good one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible in a way if you get the whole data from the main link and parse all the data according to the structure. But it is seriously unprofessional and time taking. Because you have to deal with all the HTML tags, links and values.
The best way to do is to get the API's and implement those in your app.
But if you still want to go with the first solution, then you have to keep one thing in mind, if the website's owner makes any small change in the website, it can cause your app to crash.
I won't suggest you to go with the first solution.

Check the link given below to get all the data from a website link:

[Get data from an internet link in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261859/get-data-from-an-internet-link-in-android)